# Is it accurate to calculate the focal length( with pixel unit) based on real focal length( with millimeter unit) and the sensor size

Tags: camera-calibration

I want to find the focal length of a camera. I have its physical sensor size and physical focal length. I know I can use a calibration pattern to estimate its focal length. I also can do this by: physical_focal_length / (sensor_size / resolution). I want to know which one is more accurate?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only talk about focal length. The camera matrix contains values for the optical center...

And there are lens distortion coefficients. You can rarely calculate those. You'd need to know a lot about the design of your lens.

Calibration can be better or worse than calculating from nominal/design values.

It's better if done right. It can easily be worse.

Nominal design values are a good default and starting state.

When actually building the camera and lens, there can be slight differences to the design parameters. That is why calibration is important.

Either way, you should check any solution. Given an object of known size (ruler) at a known distance (...), does it *appear* the size in pixels that you would calculate from the known size and distance? How closely?